# How to read in a .csv into Python from a weird school windows computer?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm on a school windows computer where I've downloaded Anaconda and am using Python. I'm trying to read in a .csv file.

The file definitely opens/reads in on my mac, and is sitting just on the desktop. It's 167MB, so not huge.  The encoding is UTF 8 sig.

I'm trying to load it using this pathway:

```
df = pd.read\_csv('\storage-universityname\student$\studentusername1\Desktop\filename.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', dtype=str)
```

Everytime, I get this error message:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '\storage-universityname\student$\studentusername1\Desktop\filename.csv'

​

​

I've tried editing the pathway to a combination of things, like changing all the backslashes to forward slashes, and combinations of pathways like:

```
\student$\studentusername1\Desktop\filename.csv 

\studentusername1\Desktop\filename.csv

\Desktop\filename.csv

C:\\storage-universityname\student$\studentusername1\Desktop\filename.csv
```

I've even tried using this script (can't remember now) that tells me what the pathway to this file is, and used that pathway, but it still gives me that error message. It's in the right encoding.

Ive read in files using this script plenty of times on my mac in python. I'm familiar with how to do it. Could it be that my university computer is a weird web of stuent users, so it's different to read in from?

Does anyone know how I can read in this file?

Comment: Instead of random attempts, start with finding the exact, real complete path to your file in the explorer. Then, you can use forward slashes in Python, even on Windows. If you use backslashes, make sure to use a raw string for your path : `r'C;\\...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go from the opposite, using Python, create a test.csv
next to your file.

If you manage to create a file, read test.csv

This is how you check if the path is available for the user you are working under.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = '\storage-universityname\student$\studentusername1\Desktop\filename.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig'
```

look how the system sees your given path

```
print(path)
```

> \storage-universityname\student$\studentusername1\Desktopilename.csv

**This is the output because of the backslashes "\" are used to escape characters that have a special meaning like "\n" making a new line character and I can see "\f" in your path.**

to avoid this problem just use r'' the backslashes will be treated as literal characters and not escaping characters.

```
path = r'\storage-universityname\student$\studentusername1\Desktop\filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

or your original line adding the "r" to the path

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'\storage-universityname\student$\studentusername1\Desktop\filename.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', dtype=str)
```